# trying to get user info in plugin

Tags: plugins

Building a plugin that I need to get the users info, more especially the userID

```
Class userinfo {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'get_user_info' ) );
    }
    
    public function get_user_info() {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            if ( ! ($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
                return;
        }
        return $current_user->user_info;
    }
}

$user = new userinfo();
echo $user->current_user; #echo for testing purposes
```

PHP comes back with the undefined notice and the whole thing breaks, so what am I doing wrong?

**Notice** `Undefined property: userinfo::$current_user`

**EDIT** Found a mistaken when I logged out of the site so updating here

```
Class userinfo {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'get_user_info' ) );
    }
    
    public function get_user_info() {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            if ( ! ($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
                return;
        return $current_user->user_info;
        }
    }
}

$user = new userinfo();
echo $user->current_user; #echo for testing purposes
```

Comment: Well, just as said in that PHP notice, you didn't define the `$current_user` property in your class - the one you have in `get_user_info()` is a local variable available within that function only.